# How bad are these knee walls?

Tags: framing, carpentry

First, I am going to show this to a structural engineer that I've been working with.  I am posting this to be better prepared to ask him questions.  So if you see something wrong but are not sure, please speak up.

I have knee walls in my attic.  They were put in when the attic was finished in the late 60s (we think).  The house was built in the early 50s.  The rafters are 2x6 so, according to my structural engineer, if they aren't already, the knee walls will be structural when I add insulation and more snow accumulates on the roof.

We pulled off the wall board and they're looking a bit haphazard.  This is the one that's in best shape (I think).  2x4 studs placed directly under rafters, 2 in thick top plate that they cut at an angle to be flush with vertical surface, neat blocking.

[image]

They must've run out of 2x lumber or something because the top plate is short 1x planks.  Studs are still 2x4.  The studs are placed under rafters but there are openings for a door and a built-in without a decent header so that rafter in the middle has basically no support.

[image]

The rest are constructed from 2x3 studs and the studs aren't placed under the rafters.  The top plate is 2x with the corner cut off but it breaks between studs.  It might be hard to see but toward the right, there's a stud that's supported by a foot-long end of the top plate hanging off a stud.  The rafter over the door opening doesn't get much support either.  The blocking is often loose and not wood in the best of shape.  This one was built to hold up wallboard, not the roof.

[image]

How do these look overall?  Are there problems I'm missing?

Comment: Depending on the roof span and snow loads, the knee walls may not even be needed, and are only there to define the room and for holding drywall and insulation. Typically floors are not engineered to assist in roof loads in older homes. Also typically in older homes, attics floors are not engineered for living spaces either, let alone assisting in roof support, unless they are built intentionally that way and finished at the time of original construction. Many attics are built to be just attics.

Comment: @Jack  All true and I would have preferred a house with an actual attic but that's not really an option now.  Specifically to this house, I was told by my structural engineer that the existing structure is already iffy and I need the knee walls along with a few other improvements to keep the roof up with the additional snow load if insulation is added.  He's conservative but I like to play it safe too.

Comment: Looks to me like you've hit the majority of issues to discuss with your SE. You're doing a great job of paying attention to details and picking up on things to question. In general, I'd agree with @Jack that your knee wall isn't really providing much if any structural support at all, especially if there isn't any wall underneath to take that weight.

Comment: Of course, having just read your comment, if the SE thinks additional structural support is necessary, by all means, listen to him not us! He can see the structure, take the measurements and do the calcs and it's _his_ license and livleyhood on the line if he does it wrong!

Comment: The house was built this way, the knee walls added later , why do you think this is an issue? knee walls made from 2x2 were ok.  Lumber quality back when this house was built is not even available today unless a custom old growth order from a mill like hull-oaks lumber company. I think there are 1 or 2 other old growth mills left In the US. Most is split and chipped as not many mills can handle large logs. Todays tables require almost 2x V/S when your house was built. To prove this to yourself get a #1 2x6 if you can find one take a high res pic compare to your rafters yours will be 3x denser.

Comment: I ran out of room but your own knowledge of the house it had no knee walls when built and it stood for ~10 years then they added thousands of lbs of finish work. I have added dormer windows /bays to this age house and would love to have a truckload of that stuff. The knee wall is there to hold the Sheetrock or other finish that may be desired , just an FYI dormer walls even had to be 6” and that was over 30 years ago but when this house was built 2x4 walls were the standard some say it’s for insulation, no it is because we cut Christmas trees and make lumber today ( the White House tree is 1)